# A CCSD(T) geometry optimization in Gaussian09 is deviating too far from the minimum. How do I deal with it?

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, gaussian, coupled-cluster

I am doing a CCSD(T) geometry optimization on a series of molecules. One of the geometry optimizations took about 2 weeks even though an analogous molecule with the same number of basis functions took less then 2 days to converge to a minimum. After 30 iterations, the calculation aborted with the 'error' message about exceeding the maximum number of iterations. I checked energies at different geometry optimization steps and noticed that the optimization had taken the molecule further from the minimal energy value so far. Furthermore, the bondlengths are more reasonable for the optimization step corresponding to the minimal energy value so far: the molecule should be symmetric (and it is at the 4th optimization step) but it's becoming a bit too asymmetric as the optimization progresses. Also, the energy seems to only change by a miniscule amount in the last iterations. I used the optimized geometry obtained from a CCSD calculation as the initial guess.
My route section:
#p opt=z-matrix freq=noraman rccsd(t)/genecp maxdisk=15950MB

A mixed aug-cc-pVTZ-PP/aug-cc-pVTZ basis set was used in both CCSD and CCSD(T) calculatons.

Now, I'm not sure that simply increasing the number of iterations will help... Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I tried setting MaxStep to 5. It appeared to help at first because I reached a point where 3 out of 4 convergence criteria were satisfied. Even the remaining criterion was very close to the threshold value. The first calculation (with N=30) only produced some points with 2 satisfied convergence criteria. But then the calculation with MaxStep=5 started deviating as well. So I used this point with 3 satisfied convergence criteria as the initial guess for the next calculation (setting Maxstep to 1). A similar thing happened here. Here are the respective output fragments:

MaxStep=5

```
`Maximum Force 0.000117 0.000450 YES 
RMS Force 0.000060 0.000300 YES 
Maximum Displacement 0.001992 0.001800 NO  
RMS Displacement 0.001109 0.001200 YES`
```

MaxStep=1

```
`Maximum Force 0.000116 0.000450 YES  
 RMS Force 0.000060 0.000300 YES 
 Maximum Displacement 0.001911 0.001800 NO  
 RMS Displacement 0.001007 0.001200 YES`
```

[image: Energies at different optimization steps]

Comment: What molecule is it? The (T) part is known to fail for some systems.

Comment: If you think that fourth step was close to the actual minimum, you could try restarting from there and decreasing the max step size for the optimization, as the default could potentially escape a shallow/narrow minimum. `opt=(MaxStep=N)` sets the max step to N*.01 Bohr and the default is N=30.

Comment: You might also want to include `opt=NoTrustUpdate` to keep that stepsize throughout the calculation. Have you had any further progress?

Comment: @Tyberius I tried setting maxstep to 5. It appeared to help at first because I reached a point where 3 out of 4 convergence criteria were satisfied. Even the remaining criterion was very close to the threshold value.
The first calculation (with N=30) only produced some points with 2 satisfied convergence criteria. But then the calculation with MaxStep=5 started deviating as well. So I used this point with 3 satisfied convergence criteria as the initial guess for the next calculation with Maxstep=1. A similar thing happened here. I've attached respective output fragments in another comment.

Comment: With the maxstep=1, the notrustupdate might help. Depending on the property you are interested in getting from this geometry (for example, reaction energies), it may already be converged enough. Frequencies it would be worth being cautious, but even this close to convergence might be sufficient.

Comment: @Tyberius I'll give the notrustupdate a try. Thank you! I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Hopefully it will help. When you do maxstep=1 with the default settings, it will get updated to be larger for the next step: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/136381/41556

Comment: Is CCSD(T) valid for the system? As Nike already asked above, CCSD(T) fails in some cases. If the triples correction is huge, the molecule might not even be bound at the CCSD(T) level!

Comment: @QuantumX can you tell us which molecule this is, so that we can tell you whether or not CCSD(T) is legitimate for geometry optimization? CCSD(T) will definitely not work at all geometries. It fails miserably at certain geometries.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110569/discussion-on-question-by-quantumx-a-ccsdt-geometry-optimization-in-gaussian09).

Comment: @Tyberius Thank you. NotrustUpdate with MaxStep=1 seems to have worked. I am now waiting for the frequency calculation to finish.

Comment: That's great, if you want to sum up what worked for you and some of the suggestions in the comments, it would make a good answer.

Comment: @Tyberius I will. Just waiting for the frequency calculation to finish...

Comment: Optimising in z-matrix is a bad idea, it unnecessarily restricts the algorithm. Using a tighter grid for the scf is always a good idea, as well as using much tighter convergence criteria for it. Structure optimisations usually take longer when the scf is insufficient. Btw. It would always be a good idea to include a full input file with your question, so that these issues could be reproduced.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン The thing is, G09W produces an error message whenever one doesn't use the z-matrix.

Comment: That is the windows version, right? I was unaware it lacks one of the most fundamental optimisations of Gaussian. Perhaps you can share the error. But as I said before: sharing the full input and system specifications is vital to solving your problem; especially when dealing with old software. Not being able to use redundant internal coordinates is a serious limitation and I cannot believe Gaussian would publish a software like this.

Comment: @QuantumX Did you first try to optimize your system in MP2 in G09? If you are really focussed on using CCSD(T), I would suggest you use ORCA's DLPNO-CC methods (https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/coupled-cluster) as it provide close to CC results with reduced computational cost compared to G09 or G16 implementations (https://www.faccts.de/dlpno/).

Comment: @mykd even better - I preoptimized the structure with CCSD. Thank you for your suggestion. It's just that most of the work is aready done using G09 and switching  to another software just for one calculation will look weird in this publication. At any rate, the optimization has converged (Tyberius's suggestion seems to have worked). I'm waiting for the frequency calcxulation to finish. Had to restart it several times due to power shortages.

Answer (score 5):

I'm always using CFOUR for CCSD(T) calculations, so bear with me. With CFOUR you can actually specify the irrep occupations, and works very well for the optimizations. But, there is one big snag. You need to master Z-matrices.

Now back to your question. If you know it should be symmetric, why not simply impose symmetry?

Comment: Good point. Molpro, MRCC, OpenMOLCAS and other codes allow this too.

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer to your particular problem, but a summary of the methods suggested for dealing with the headline issue of a diverging geometry optimization.

- Step size: if you are drifting away from what you believe to be a minimum, decreasing the size of each optimization step can help you avoid jumping out of a small well around the minimum.
- Guess: if you want to do a high level geometry optimization, always start from a structure obtained by a reliable lower level method. Getting the search into the approximate region of the minimum can save a lot of computational time even for less tricky optimizations.
- Validity (method): make sure the method you are using gives reasonable energy for the system you are studying. If converging a single point energy at the CCSD(T) level is challenging or is producing unreasonable results, the forces and thus the optimization are likely to be unreliable as well.
- Validity (computation): even if your overall level of theory is fine, your results can still be skewed if you aren't converging the energy tightly enough. Properties require tighter convergence than what is needed to get an accurate energy. The noise in a loosely converged energy can cause an optimization to bounce around erratically.

Comment: Tighter convergence and (it applicable) tighter grid for the scf should always be the first point of entry. If your energies are fuzzy, your derived properties will, and your calculation will oscillate.